How to count Facebook ads use dynamic creative
From Facebook document: https://www.facebook.com/business/help/652738434773716
"You can have up to 5,000 ads. Only 1,000 of these 5,000 ads can use dynamic creative."
Some my adaccounts have an issue "Your account xxxx has reached the maximum number of dynamic creative ads allowed (1,000). Please delete some of your older ads."
How can I count ads that are using "dynamic creative"?
Note: I can count ads by
        $adAccount = new AdAccount($adAccountId);

        $cursor = $adAccount->getAds(
            params: [
                'date_preset' => 'today',
                'summary' => 'total_count',
                'limit' => 1,
            ]
        );

It is great if I can find an API to get numbers ads use dynamic creative belong to each adaccount
